# Does a child method not have access to a parent method's variables?

Tags: php, oop, syntax, scope

It's not a child method per say, but it's a method that's called inside another method in my class `Paginate`.

When I try to run this:

```
public function paginate() {
    // Other stuff here 
    for ($i = $pageMin; (($i <= $pageMax) && ($i <= $this->arrayLength)); $i++) {
    $this->build(); // The important bit! 
    }
    // Other stuff here 
}

public function build() {
    echo $array[$i]['name'];
}
```

I get told that `$i is undefined` on the line where the echo is called for my `build()` method. Why is this? Does a method called inside another not inherit variables from the parent method? Isn't `$i` relatively global from `build()`'s perspective?

How do I solve this? Do I have to pass `$i` to `build()` as a parameter when I call it inside `paginate()`? That doesn't exactly seem clean. Alternatives?

Comment: @user814064 Why? This is PHP, not Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in different scope.

You have to pass it with a parameter.

```
$this->build($i);
```

--

```
public function build($i) {
    echo $array[$i]['name'];
}
```